# What is the function of the following SQL ISNULL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

I have an ISNULL statement that I'm not sure how it would process.

```
ISNULL(a, ISNULL(a, m))
```

Is the inner ISNULL statement redundant and can I replace with the following?

```
ISNULL(a, m)
```

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Comment: Yes, it's redundant.  Your second statement looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It is redundant.